# Delete all matching pairs of a character from a string

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to make a code that deletes the repeated characters. For example - if we have a string `"aabacdc"`, we want to make it as `"abd"`. If the character exists twice in the string, then we delete both characters as we did in the above example. The `'a'` occurs 3 times in our string, so we just deleted the 2 `a` and left 1 remaining.

What I'm trying to do in this code is use two nested `for` loops - first for loop to compare the first character with the other characters. If the character has a duplicate in the string, then just delete both the characters. How can I fix this code?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str2 = input.nextLine();

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(str2);

    for (int k = 0; k < str.length() - 1; k++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (str.charAt(k) == str.charAt(i)) {
                str.deleteCharAt(k);
                str.deleteCharAt(i);
            } 
        }
    }

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Comment: You never gave us logic for _which_ letter is retained.  Also, if there were six `a` present, would we retain one or two?

Comment: do you mean abcd as the ouput not only abd? because you have a 'c' in your input

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen jobeth  So, let's say if we have input "aaa" it must print "a". 2) if we have input "aabb" it will print nothing. 3) so it means if we have the character occurs two times in a string then delete it. 3) if we have input "aabbacc" it will print "a"

Comment: Is it binary? Odd numbers of `a` stay, even numbers of `a` - remove it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch exactly

Comment: @ElliottFrisch can you please check what's wrong with my logic? Thanks

Comment: Rather a lot I'm afraid. Your algorithm is incomplete.

Comment: so 'b' is not remove because it is odd?

Comment: @jobethbillien right

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why is it incomplete? can you please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of what you're trying to do based on your expected output is that you want to remove characters from the string 1 pair at a time. So if there is an odd number of a character in the string, 1 should remain, and if there's an even number 0 should remain.

Any time you're removing elements from a structure while you're iterating by index, you need to loop over the structure backwards, so that the index values don't shift as you delete elements. This means you should only delete elements which the outer loop is currently at, or has already seen (i.e. only delete elements at indexes `>= i`).

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = input.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

for (int i = sb.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < sb.length(); j++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(j)) {
            sb.deleteCharAt(j);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(sb);
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/9LtZlf)

Comment: If you delete the character at `i`, all the characters to the right of `i` will shift to the left, which means the next character would be at `i`, not `i + 1`. Iterating backwards prevents that shift from being a problem, because the next character will always be at `i - 1`.